# Slider Value Display with jQuery UI - 2 handles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I want to build a slider with two handles with the handle value displayed within the handles or above them. I have done so far.

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 3600,
        max: 86400,
    values: [ 28800, 86400 ]
});
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user3266989 If you found the solution yourself, post it here for others to refer.

Answer (score 1):

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3g6nY/13/) . IF you have any confusions, don't hesitate to ask me.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [75, 300],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var value1 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
            var value2 = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
            $("#slider-range").find(".ui-slider-handle:first").text(value1);
                        $("#slider-range").find(".ui-slider-handle:last").text(value2);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-slider-handle{
    width: 35px !important;
    font-size: small !important;
    color: #FF0000 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```