# Dynamically creating jQuery UI sliders: I want to set unique ids for both slider handles to give them custom text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm dynamically creating jQuery UI sliders, using the following code in a forEach loop:

```
            // Sets an id for the slider handles, gives them a custom class (makes them appear as circles, centers them)    
            $("#slideRange" + i).find(".ui-slider-handle").attr("id","slideHandle" + i).addClass("customSliderHandle");
            // These two lines set the times below the slider handles.
            $("#timeSlider" + i).find(".slideStartLabel").text(startTime);
            $("#timeSlider" + i).find(".slideEndLabel").text(endTime);
```

This successfully makes the following slider, with variable times, for every iteration:

[image]

What I'd like to do, instead of showing the times below the circular handles, is have the times appear in the middle of the handles. The end result would look like this (photoshopped):

[image]

The times will then update, according to the slider values, within the "slide" event callback.

My question is: how do I assign unique id's to the two slider handles, so that I can then set their text independently in the "slide" callback? The code I wrote above gives both handles the same id. Using this id to set text to a handle will only apply to the first handle, leaving me no way to change the text of the second. Using find(), get(), or just $(".ui-slider-handle") are all ways of getting an array of the slider handles, but when I try attr("id","uniqueId") on one of the elements of that array, I get "(...).method(...) is not a method".

Or is assigning unique id's the wrong approach, here? Is there a jQuery or vanilla Js way of setting attributes of one element at a time, when searching by class and getting potentially multiple results?

Also, for context: I'm using find() because I'm using clone() on a markup shell, then appending it to a central div. Here's the shell:

```
    <!-- This hidden div will be cloned, customized, and appended onto .modal-body -->
<div id="timeslotShell" class="timeslot row" style="display:none">
  <div class="container-fluid slotContents" id="slotContents">
    <span class="col-md-4"> Listing <div class="slotNumber listNum">*Listing No.*</div>: From <div class="slotNumber startNumber slotStartShell"> *Start Time* </div> until 
      <div class="slotNumber endNumber slotEndShell"> *End Time* </div> </span> 
    <div class="col-md-8"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-info slotButton">
        Choose A Time From Within These Hours
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="timeSliderShell" class="collapse timeSlider">
      <br><br>
      <div id="slider-range" class="slideRange row"></div>
      <div id="slideLabels" class="slideLabels slideRange row">
        <div class="slideStartLabel"></div><div class="slideEndLabel"></div> 
      </div>  
    </div>          
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool -- as luck with have it, I found the answer shortly after posting this. Check this post if you're dealing with a similar issue:

[Slider Value Display with jQuery UI - 2 handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534628/slider-value-display-with-jquery-ui-2-handles)

All that's needed, in the .find() calls, is

```
.find(".ui-slider-handle:first").text(value1);
```

for the first handle and then

```
.find(".ui-slider-handle:last").text(value2);
```

for the second.